# Issue while using switch statement with numbers ranges in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I've been trying to create a code in JavaScript using the switch statement to calculate the income tax for Brazilian residents. I know I can do that using if-else, which I already did and worked perfectly. However, I want to enhance my skills, and so I'm trying the same income tax table now using switch.
The code has been created, however no matter what number I use as salary, the result always goes straight to the default block, executing that very last string piece.
Could anyone please advise on where my mistake is?

```
console.log(`INCOME TAX TABLE 2023 - BRAZIL`);
const salary = 2000;

switch (salary) {
    case (salary < 1904):
        console.log(`You're exempt from paying taxes this year`);
        break;
    case (salary >= 1904 && salary < 2827):
        console.log(`You fell in the 7.5% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.075}`);
        break;
    case (salary >= 2827 && salary < 3751):
        console.log(`You fell in the 15% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.15}`);
        break;
    case (salary >= 3751 && salary < 4665):
        console.log(`You fell in the 22.5% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.225}`);
        break;
    default:
        console.log(`You fell in the 27.5% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.275}`);
}
```

Comment: Please, take a [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

The switch expression is compared with case expressions.
Here the case expressions are boolean (true/false).
So in switch use the true, to get the case with the truth.

```
console.log(`INCOME TAX TABLE 2023 - BRAZIL`);
const salary = 2000;

switch (true) {
    case (salary < 1904):
        console.log(`You're exempt from paying taxes this year`);
        break;
    case (salary >= 1904 && salary < 2827):
        console.log(`You fell in the 7.5% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.075}`);
        break;
    case (salary >= 2827 && salary < 3751):
        console.log(`You fell in the 15% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.15}`);
        break;
    case (salary >= 3751 && salary < 4665):
        console.log(`You fell in the 22.5% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.225}`);
        break;
    default:
        console.log(`You fell in the 27.5% category. The amount of income tax you must pay is ${salary * 0.275}`);
}
```

Comment: This is absolute genius! I was writing an answer saying that it was not possible, and then saw this! (However I would still recommend people do `if-else` for this, woudln't you, Agria?)

Comment: I don't know about genius, considering the same answer was written 13 years ago.... ;)

Comment: In such simple cases I would use if-else, but that is a personal matter of writing style. Genius! no... patient yes...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `switch` statements in this way. You're giving each case a boolean expression which resolves to `true` or `false`. Neither of those two values will ever be equal to `2000` (the value of `salary`) so no case is matched and the default is hit.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind answers and awesome inputs!

Answer (score 1):

You can't but true/false statement in a switch case. Switch case is meant to be used if you have a variable with multiple answer. Say the answer can be 1, 2, 3, or 4. You can put multiple segment of int in that range. For that purpose, you might want to stick to if else statement.